# Proper value for timestamp?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add in values TIMESTAMP to my database but the it is not working. When I delete the timestamp row in my DB, every value adds and gets inserted.  Do i need to set $timestamp to something different for my value?

```
$exam_name = $data["name"];
$exam_points = $data["total_score"];
$exam_grade = NULL;
$release_status = 0;
$exam_comments = NULL;
$exam_ucid = NULL;
$timestamp = NULL;


$sql = "INSERT INTO exams (exam_name, exam_grade, release_status, total_score, exam_comments, 
our_ucid, timestamp )
            VALUES 
            ('$exam_name', '$exam_grade', '$release_status', '$exam_points', '$exam_comments', 
'$exam_ucid', '$timestamp')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: You need to set `$timestamp` to a valid date and time in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: You can use the `date()` function to format the current time.

Comment: If the column has `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, then just leave the column out of the `INSERT` query and it will be filled in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

timestamp is a keyword, you have to change field name
e.g. timestamp1